# Analytical form of a complex but simple multivariate integral

Tags: probability, integration

Given $\{\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...\}, \{\mu_0,\mu_1,...\}$, $\{t_0,t_1\}$, we define the function $P: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
 $$P(n)=  \displaystyle\int_{0}^{t_0}\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{t_0}...\displaystyle\int_{x_{n-1}}^{t_0} e^{x_{\color{blue}{0}}(\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_{\color{blue}{0}})}{\color{blue} \cdots} e^{x_{\color{blue}{n}}(\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_{\color{blue}{n}})}$$ $$\cdot[1-e^{-\mu_{\color{blue}{0}}(t_1-\sum_i^{{\color{blue}{0}}} x_i)}]{\color{blue} \cdots} [1-e^{-\mu_{\color{blue}{n}}(t_1-\sum_{i}^{{\color{blue}{n}}} x_i)}] dx_n ...dx_1dx_0$$

My first question (for mathematicians) is, can you find an analytical form (without the integrals) for this function?

My second question (for programers), can you define that function in R?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems the most inner integral with $x_n$ as the lower limit should not be there?

Comment: yes, good point. Thanks, I just changed.